# Запись новых значений в JSON файл node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Мне нужно добавление новых значений в JSON файл и сохранять его (и ничего большего, я много искал но всё выглядело не нужным)
Просто хотелось спросить конкретно что нужно сделать для того чтобы добавить новое значение в JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал поискать по запросу "node add value to json file".

Первая ссылка в гугле привела к решению:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093141/379949

Как говорят у нас в Симферополе: inglish - eto sila!

Comment: Почему я нигде раньше не находил json.push (а на английском я тоже искал, просто нигде не упомянали json.push)

Comment: @Cilian `json.push` это не метод `json`, это метод массива, который был распарсен из `json` _append your new result to the array_, если у вас не массив в файле, то так не получится сделать

Comment: Да, я знал что это метод для массивов, просто не догадывался до этого (json.push назвал потому что в том вопросе на которую sneas дал ссылку написали так)